# Using custom font for different trait collections in storyboard doesn't reflect in app

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, storyboard

When I'm using custom font for a UILabel or UIButton for multiple trait collection **through storyboard** like in the following picture I am facing an issue in UI updation while running either in simulator or in device.
The issue is instead of the custom font system font gets assigned while running the app. 
[image]

FYI

- When I use the same custom font for default single trait collection the font is reflecting successfully. But the same fails if I use it for different traits.
- And if we apply the font for different trait collection **through code**  as shown in the following snippet the UI is updating successfully.

  if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(traitCollection)]) {
              if ((self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact) && (self.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular)) {
                  self.customButtonFont = [UIFont customFontWithSize:18.0f];
              }
          }

Does anyone know the reason for this issue and can I achieve this through storyboard itself ?

Comment: It sounds like a fair use case for a bug report. File the bug report and use your code workaround.

Comment: i'm running into the same problem, except I can't get a static cell to take on the trait. But when the UITableView that contains this UILabel dequeues a dynamic cell, the traits seem to be correct. Nor sure why.